# jCrop selection box overlap by the image in IE

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, internet-explorer, jcrop

I'm trying to use jcrop for image cropping project that i am working on. i found this example how jcrop can use with a asp.net project. This work fine in chrome, Firefox and IE 11 but in IE 9 and 10 this doesn't work. It seems like the image is overlapping the jcrop selection box. Here is the code snippet and i have uploaded the complete project into github : https://github.com/asankamadushan/jCropTestProject. Any idea why this is not working in IE 9 and 10.

```
<code>
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="JCorpExample._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.Jcrop.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.Jcrop.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.Jcrop.css" type="text/css" />
<script language="Javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#cropbox').Jcrop({
        onSelect: updateCoords
        });
    });     
    function updateCoords(c) {
        jQuery('#X').val(c.x);
        jQuery('#Y').val(c.y);
        jQuery('#W').val(c.w);
        jQuery('#H').val(c.h);
    };          
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" Text="Corp Image" 
onclick="Submit_Click" />
<br />
<br />
<asp:Image ID="cropedImage" runat="server" Visible="False" />
<br />
<br />

<img src="Sunset.jpg" id="cropbox" />

<asp:HiddenField ID="X" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="Y" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="W" runat="server" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="H" runat="server" />

</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
</code>
```